# Python inheritance and scoping question

Tags: python

Edited because I'm a moron. Should have said class originally.

I have the code that does something like this:

file1.py

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    stuff_here()

class B(object):
  def func(self):
    self.a = A()
```

file2.py

```
import file1
class A(file1.A):
  def __init__(self):
    file1.A(self)
    self.thing = other_thing

class B(file1.B):
  pass
```

I would like that when I instantiate file2.B() it uses file2.A() for its member a, not file1.A()

Is there a way to do this? I tried looking at the python scoping rules but I'm misunderstanding it I think.

Comment: Maybe `Object` should be `class`.

Comment: Could you be a little more concrete about what you're trying to build? Then maybe we can contribute alternative suggestions.

Comment: I am extending a system that already has some classes that have quite a lot of code in them. I need to change 1 tiny implementation detail of class A, as the original class makes a assumption that doesn't hold true for my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class attribute to hold the class you would like to use.  In the first file, use

```
class B(object):
    A = A
    def func(self):
        self.a = self.A()
```

and in the second file, use

```
class B(file1.B):
    A = A
```

Probably there is a better way of achieving whatever you want to achieve...

**Edit**: Your comment to your question suggests that you don't want to actually change the code in the first file.  In this case, you could try to "monkey patch" `file1.py`.  Write `file2.py` as

```
import file1

class A(file1.A):
    def __init__(self):
        file1.A(self)
        self.thing = other_thing

file1.A = A
```

Now you actually substituted `file1.A` by your own version.  This is certainly hacky, but sometimes the quickest way to get somewhere.

Comment: +1 but with reservations.  While it should do what the OP is asking for, I can't help but feel whatever OP's really trying to accomplish could be better done some other way.

Comment: This certainly worked, but it does feel like a hack. I can at least move on until I figure out something more elegant. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in the parent that returns the class to use, and override it in the child.